# Justifying that infinite sum of solutions to wave equation is also a solution

Tags: sequences-and-series, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation

I'm currently learning about the separation of variables technique for solving $u_{tt} = c^2 u_{xx}, \; 0 < x < l$ with $u(0,t) = 0 = u(l,t)$ (section 4.1 of Partial Differential Equations by Strauss). After showing that $$u_n(x,t) = \bigg(A_n \cos \frac{n \pi c t}{l} + B_n \sin \frac{n \pi ct}{l}\bigg) \sin \frac{n \pi x}{l}$$
is a solution for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and arbitrary constants $A_n$ and $B_n$, the book goes on to give the general solution as an infinite sum:
$$u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg(A_n \cos \frac{n \pi c t}{l} + B_n \sin \frac{n \pi c t}{l}\bigg) \sin \frac{n \pi x}{l}.$$
My question is: what justifies asserting that the *infinite* sum is also a solution? I agree that any finite sum $\sum_{n=1}^N u_n(x,t)$ is also a solution by the superposition principle (a.k.a. linearity), but in the book this principle is stated specifically for *finite* sums. Could someone provide me some justification for this? I would like to see a rigorous argument if it's not too complicated, or at least the main ideas behind the argument. Thanks!

Comment: The idea behind this is that, under certain convergence conditions, $\partial \sum u_n=\sum\partial u_n$. In your case, the general solution can be written as such a sum since the series converge"nicely", given certain assumptions on the smoothness of the solution the sum is converging to

Comment: I believe that you can use induction to show that the superposition principle also holds for infinite series. But, this certainly isn't true for all infinite series as the series must satisfy convergence criteria.

Comment: In particular, if $u_n$ (as functions of $x$) are analytic in an open region of the complex plane in which the series $\sum_n |u_n|$ converges  uniformly, then $\sum_n u_n$ is also analytic there and $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \sum_n u_n = \sum_n \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} u_n $.

Comment: @Axion004 - induction is how you show it is true for all finite sums, but it does not show it is true for infinite sums. Induction shows a statement $P(n)$ is true for all natural numbers $n$. But $\infty$ is not a natural number.